# is this known and what is it called?

Tags: terminology, arithmetic

I noticed that
XXX...n * Y = YYY...n *  X

for example

999    * 8   = 888   *  9  = 7992

77777 *  9   = 99999 *  7  = 699993

13 * 777  = 7 * (1300 + 130 + 13 )  = 10101

19 * 7777 = 7 * ( 19000 + 1900 + 190 + 19) = 147763

what is this property called? or is it known before?

Comment: It is called “commutativity of the multiplication” – $999 \cdot 8 = 111 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 =  111 \cdot 8 \cdot 9 = 888 \cdot 9$

Comment: I don't believe there is a standard term for this but since "aaa...a" (n times) is equal to "a(111...1)" it is not hard to show that (XXX...X)Y= X(111...1)Y=  X(YYY...Y).

Comment: $X\ldots X\cdot Y = (X\cdot 1\ldots 1)\cdot Y = X\cdot Y\cdot 1\ldots 1 = Y\ldots Y\cdot X$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Why did you tag this [tag:matrices]?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I changed it

Answer (score 1):

This property is called "representation in base 10" and "the multiplication is commutative".
For any $X$ and $Y$ the following equalities hold:
$$
\underbrace{XX\ldots X}_{n\text{ times}}=X\cdot \underbrace{11\ldots 1}_{n\text{ times}}
$$
So 
$$
\underbrace{XX\ldots X}_{n\text{ times}}\cdot Y=X\cdot Y\cdot  \underbrace{11\ldots 1}_{n\text{ times}}=\underbrace{YY\ldots Y}_{n\text{ times}}\cdot X
$$

Comment: Associativity of multiplication is also used in the problem.